# PHP，UTF-8 decode

Tags: php, utf-8, decode, encode

I've encoded some text(Chinese characters), which now seems like:

```
%u30102009%u7EA7%u3011%u672A%u63D0%u4EA4%u5B9E%u4E60%u6587%u4EF6%u7684%u540C%u5B66%u8BF7%u5C3D%u5FEB%u63D0%u4EA4
```

Then, how can I decode it to UTF-8 in PHP?

Comment: This is UTF. Ascii is a number

Comment: sorry， I just mean how to decode it?

Comment: if it's a json encoded string, it must use \ instead of %

Comment: I use escape(text) in JS to encode it.

Comment: @Lazy.TJU I don't understand, how did you get percentages. I tried to escape text '程式檔名' here: http://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html#ad-output And got: \u7A0B\u5F0F\u6A94\u540D. No percentages as you see.

Answer (score 0):

This is UTF. You cannot "decode" UTF you can change the encoding. I assume you want to save this to a database in which case you can just insert this and it will be alright. However if my assumption is not correct you can use [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

Comment: Yes, you are right.Actually, I've got some Chinese characters and encode them using escape() methods in JS and save them to database using PHP(AJAX). However, now that I retrieve it, I can not decode them to what they originally are. What should I do?

Comment: have your database collation be utf8_bin